# Asking for the installation of Caffe

Tags: caffe

I was installing the Caffe library on Mac OS, but when I type 'make run test', I encountered the following problem.  What should I do? Thanks in advance. My macbook doesn't contain Cudas, does this affect the installation?

---

```
.build_release/test/test_all.testbin 0 --gtest_shuffle 
Cuda number of devices: 32767
Setting to use device 0
Current device id: 0
Current device name: 
Note: Randomizing tests' orders with a seed of 14037 .
[==========] Running 1927 tests from 259 test cases.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 4 tests from BlobSimpleTest/0, where TypeParam = f
[ RUN      ] BlobSimpleTest/0.TestPointersCPUGPU
E0306 11:45:15.035683 2126779136 common.cpp:104] Cannot create Cublas handle. Cublas won't be available.
E0306 11:45:15.114891 2126779136 common.cpp:111] Cannot create Curand generator. Curand won't be available.
F0306 11:45:15.115012 2126779136 syncedmem.cpp:55] Check failed: error == cudaSuccess (35 vs. 0)  CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version
*** Check failure stack trace: ***
    @        0x10d2c976a  google::LogMessage::Fail()
    @        0x10d2c8f14  google::LogMessage::SendToLog()
    @        0x10d2c93c7  google::LogMessage::Flush()
    @        0x10d2cc679  google::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()
    @        0x10d2c9a4f  google::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()
    @        0x10e023406  caffe::SyncedMemory::to_gpu()
    @        0x10e022c5e  caffe::SyncedMemory::gpu_data()
    @        0x108021d9c  caffe::BlobSimpleTest_TestPointersCPUGPU_Test<>::TestBody()
    @        0x10849ba5c  testing::internal::HandleExceptionsInMethodIfSupported<>()
    @        0x10848a1ba  testing::Test::Run()
    @        0x10848b0e2  testing::TestInfo::Run()
    @        0x10848b7d0  testing::TestCase::Run()
    @        0x108491f86  testing::internal::UnitTestImpl::RunAllTests()
    @        0x10849c264  testing::internal::HandleExceptionsInMethodIfSupported<>()
    @        0x108491c99  testing::UnitTest::Run()
    @        0x107f8c89a  main
    @     0x7fff903e15c9  start
    @                0x3  (unknown)
make: *** [runtest] Abort trap: 6
```

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue. But i have a Graphic card specifically to run Caffe on it, so CPU_ONLY was not an option ;-)

To check if it's the same cause that mine, try to run CUDA Samples [deviceQuery example](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-linux/index.html#running-binaries)

I fixed using [CUDA Guide runfile verifications](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#runfile-verifications)

```
sudo chmod 0666 /dev/nvidia*
```

Comment: saved my life. Thanks

Comment: @RafaelRuiz Happy to help :-)

Answer (score -2):

Finally, I find a solution by setting CPU_ONLY := 1 in Makefile.config (uncomment the original one by removing the '#' in line "CPU_ONLY := 1 in Makefile.config") and rerun the command"make clean", "make all", then "make test", then "make runtest" referring to this link - https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/736

Comment: This only "fixes" things by **not** using your expensive graphics card.